# Определение читаемой кодировки

Tags: php, кодировка, csv

Имеются .csv файлы.
Внутри и латиница и кирилица
как определеить кодировку чтобы была информации читаема ->пробую так

```
<?php

$data=parse_ini_file('info.ini',true);

$f=fopen ('news.csv','rt')or die("ЧЕРТ!");

for ($i=0;$data=fgetcsv($f,1000,';');$i++)
{
//    Считаем кол-во полей в строке ограничитель коретка
//   кол-во полей в строке
    $num=count($data);

    echo "<h3> Строка номер $i (полей : $num):</h3>";
    for ($c=0;$c<$num;$c++){
        $br=mb_convert_encoding( $data[$c], 'utf8');
        echo"[$c]: .$br <br>";
    }
}
fclose($f);
```

Получаю вот это

```
Строка номер 0 (полей : 6):

[0]: .ID 
[1]: .title 
[2]: .text 
[3]: .author 
[4]: .date 
[5]: .img 
Строка номер 1 (полей : 6):

[0]: .1 
[1]: .ãà®àâ ¨«¨ ¦¨§­ì 
[2]: .¥¬ ¡«¨¦¥ ­ ç «® âãà¨áâ¨ç¥áª®£® á¥§®­ , â¥¬ ¤ «ìè¥ ®â âãà¨áâ¨ç¥áª®£® ®«¨¬¯  ®â¤ «ï¥âáï ãàæ¨ï. ç¥à¥¤­®© ­¥£ â¨¢ ? ¯à¥¤ã¯à¥¦¤¥­¨¥ ®¡ ã£à®§¥ â¥à ªâ®¢ ¢ â ¬¡ã«¥ ¨ ­â «ì¥, ®¯ã¡«¨ª®¢ ­­®¥ ¤«ï  ¬¥à¨ª ­áª¨å £à ¦¤ ­ ­  áâà ­¨æ¥ ¯®á®«ìáâ¢   ¢ ãàæ¨¨. á«¨ à ­ìè¥ ¢ ®ä¨æ¨ «ì­ëå ¯à¥¤ã¯à¥¦¤¥­¨ïå  ¥«¨ª®¡à¨â ­¨¨, ¥à¬ ­¨¨, §à ¨«ï ¨ àï¤  ¤àã£¨å áâà ­ ¢ ª ç¥áâ¢¥ ®¯ á­ëå ¬¥áâ ä¨£ãà¨à®¢ «¨ â ¬¡ã« ¨ î£®-¢®áâ®ç­ë¥ ¯à®¢¨­æ¨¨ ãàæ¨¨, â® â¥¯¥àì ¢¯¥à¢ë¥ ¢ íâ®¬ ç¥à­®¬ á¯¨áª¥ ®ª § «áï á ¬ë© ¬ áá®¢ë© âãà¥æª¨© ªãà®àâ. 
[3]: .1 
[4]: .13.04.2016 
[5]: .1 
Строка номер 2 (полей : 6):

[0]: .2 
[1]: .®§£ ¯®¤ ª¨á«®â®© 
[2]: .à ¢­¨â¥«ì­® ­¥¤ ¢­® §  àã¡¥¦®¬ ¡ë«¨ à §à¥è¥­ë ¨áá«¥¤®¢ ­¨ï ¬®§£®¢®© ¤¥ïâ¥«ì­®áâ¨ ç¥«®¢¥ª  á ¨á¯®«ì§®¢ ­¨¥¬ ¯á¨å®âà®¯­ëå ¢¥é¥áâ¢.  ª¨¬ ¨­â¥à¥á­ë¬ á¯®á®¡®¬ ­ ãª  ¯ëâ ¥âáï ¯®­ïâì, ª ª à ¡®â îâ ¬¥å ­¨§¬ë, ä®à¬¨àãîé¨¥ ­ è¥ á®§­ ­¨¥. ?¥­â .àã? ®§­ ª®¬¨« áì á ¯¥à¥¤­¨¬ ªà ¥¬ ?¯á¨å®¤¥«¨ç¥áª®© ­ ãª¨? ¨ à ááª §ë¢ ¥â ® â®¬, çâ® ¯à®¨áå®¤¨â á ­¥à¢­ë¬¨ ª«¥âª ¬¨ ?¯®¤ ª¨á«®â®©? 
[3]: .3 
[4]: .12.04.2016 
[5]: .2 
Строка номер 3 (полей : 3):

[0]: .3 
[1]: . ¯à®«ì¥âáï §®«®â®© ¤®¦¤ì 
[2]: .áâ «®áì ¢á¥£® ¯ïâì ¤­¥© ¤® ¥à¥¬®­¨¨ ¢àãç¥­¨ï ¯à¥¬¨¨ ?®«®â ï ¬ áª ?.  áã¡¡®âã ¢¥ç¥à®¬ ¯à¨ ¡®«ìè®¬ áâ¥ç¥­¨¨ â¥ âà «ì­®£® ­ à®¤  ­  áæ¥­ã ®áª®¢áª®£® ¬ã§ëª «ì­®£® â¥ âà  ¨¬¥­¨ â ­¨á« ¢áª®£® ¨ ¥¬¨à®¢¨ç - ­ç¥­ª® ¢ë©¤ãâ ¢¥¤ãé¨¥, ¢áªà®îâ ª®­¢¥àâë ? ¨ ¢áï áâà ­  ã§­ ¥â, ª ª¨¥ á¯¥ªâ ª«¨ ¯à®è«®£® á¥§®­  áâ «¨ « ãà¥ â ¬¨. ® íâ®£® ¬®¬¥­â  ­ §¢ âì íâ¨ ¯®áâ ­®¢ª¨ ¨ ¨å  ¢â®à®¢-áç áâ«¨¢æ¥¢ ­¥ á¬®£ãâ ¤ ¦¥ ç«¥­ë ¦îà¨: £®«®á®¢ ­¨¥ â ©­®¥, ¨ à¥§ã«ìâ â ¡ã¤¥â ¨§¢¥áâ¥­ â®«ìª® ­  æ¥à¥¬®­¨¨. ® ¥áâì ª ¦¤ë©  ªâ¥à, à¥¦¨áá¥à ¨«¨ áæ¥­®£à ä, ¢®è¥¤è¨© ¢ ¢ëá®ªãî ª®¬¨áá¨î, ¬®¦¥â ïà®áâ­® ã¡¥¦¤ âì ª®««¥£, çâ® ¢®â íâ®â á¯¥ªâ ª«ì ? ¯à¥ªà á¥­,   ¢®â â®â ? ¯®«­®¥ ¡¥§®¡à §¨¥, ¨ ª®««¥£¨ ¡ã¤ãâ á®çã¢áâ¢¥­­® ª¨¢ âì, ­® £®«®áã¥â ª ¦¤ë© ç«¥­ ¦îà¨ ­ ¥¤¨­¥ á® á¢®¨¬ «¨áâ®çª®¬ ¡ã¬ £¨ (ª®â®àë¥ åà ­ïâáï ¯®â®¬ ¢ ¤¨à¥ªæ¨¨ ¢® ¨§¡¥¦ ­¨¥ ®¡¢¨­¥­¨© ¢ ­¥¯à ¢¨«ì­®¬ ¯®¤áç¥â¥). ®íâ®¬ã ­  æ¥à¥¬®­¨¨ áîà¯à¨§ë ¡ë¢ îâ ¤ ¦¥ ¤«ï ç«¥­®¢ ¦îà¨ ? çâ® ã¦ £®¢®à¨âì ® ¯ã¡«¨ª¥ ¨ ¦ãà­ «¨áâ å, ª®â®àë¥ á«¥¤ïâ §  å®¤®¬ ä¥áâ¨¢ «ï. 
Строка номер 4 (полей : 4):

[0]: . à¥¤áª § âì « ãà¥ â®¢ ­¥¢®§¬®¦­®, ¬®¦­® «¨èì ¯®¯à®¡®¢ âì ã£ ¤ âì 
[1]: .2 
[2]: .13.04.2016 
[3]: .3
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348802/how-can-i-output-a-utf-8-csv-in-php-that-excel-will-read-properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо пользователю " ugin_root " на форуме sql.ru который помог кому-то с похожей проблемой еще 5 лет назад...

***Решение:***

> iconv('CP866','utf-8',$data[$c]);

Answer (score 0):

В PHP есть функция `mb_detect_encoding`, но, к сожалению она не работает для русских кодировок.
Почитайте здесь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/107945/ там есть и ссылки и отдельное решение.